# Relative silverlight control positioning

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I Have a canvas and would like to place silverlight elements within that canvas relative to each.

For example, I have an element (A) at canvas.top="0" canvas.left="5". I would like to place all elements proceeding that one relative to its position. So if i move A to canvas.top="10" canvas.left="15" all other elements would reposition themselves.

IF this is feasibly with a canvas let me know, else can you recommend what control i should be using. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canvas isn't designed for this. It sounds like you want a Grid or StackPanel inside the Canvas.